# Embed editable Google spreadsheet with ranges

Tags: google-sheets, iframe

I have a google spreadsheet with a form include.

I can embed the form using the publish to the web option, but this way the form is not editable.

`<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTK0P8DqQ-2fBqZAsDLuMI6w1M6awp0Vebx-WJNCppVER5wFp12GoGsfjLpDLBIp1cCOdT-7yFKFVdi/pubhtml?gid=0&amp;widget=false&amp;headers=false&amp;chrome=false&amp" width="710" height="500"></iframe>`

So, I have changed the url of the iframe with the address of the shared form (`edit?usp=sharing`).

`<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cedHsKEsSqzwVbY4ZVuopf48MAozhEMwG6AQMaRK530/edit?usp=sharing?&amp;rm=minimal&amp;single=true&amp;range=B1:B1&amp" width="710" height="500"></iframe>`

However, my wish is for it to look like the first iframe.

With `rm=minimal&amp` I was able to hide some elements, but I don't have the same result as the other way of embedding (first iframe).

[image: Iframes]

Thanks.